# Make SKShapeNode line draw itself

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have a path and I want to make a line of SKShapeNode to draw itself along this path, then I want the user to draw this path only if his touch match the path.

Comment: That's ... kind of vague. Can you please explain a bit more and also post the code you have, explain what it should be doing and also what it is doing.

Comment: I just need the approach to solve this problem, I don't have the code yet.

Comment: Well that’s not really how SO works, as it’s for specific programming problems. Even so, it’s not really clear what your are asking - can you explain what you mean by ‘I have a path’ and how is the user supposed to draw the path? How can his touch ‘match the path’ unless the path is already onscreen is some form?